# create transparent text on circle

Tags: inkscape

I want to create a transparent text on a circle with inkscape.

I managed to create a circle with a color, created a text and converted it into an object, and resized canvas to drawing.

Thats my result:

[image]

However, I would like to make the text transparent. So that the color from the text in the circle, is identical to the background color where the svg is used.

If I make the text transparent, I get of course only a blank circle.

Is there an option to cut the text out of the circle or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

I found a way.

Select Circle + Text and then click on `Path->Difference`

Comment: Also see: https://inkscape.org/learn/faq/#how-make-hole-solid-object-hole-donut